# Dynamic Moving Average per Day based on multiple values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to achieve a Moving Average per Day with a dynamic adjustment. This would be so that if a parameter value was set to 3, the average would be taken over those 3 days and the next average would be the next 3 days.
My issue is that I have multiple values per day and seem to be struggling with that. I have already made a moving average based on individual values but I also need the one based on Day.

Currently what I have is a table ('TBUData') like this:

| Date | Value | Moving Avg Per Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/05/2023 | 9.03 | 9.03 |
| 15/05/2023 |  | 5.71 |
| 15/05/2023 |  | 5.71 |
| 15/05/2023 | 5.38 | 5.71 |
| 15/05/2023 | 5.53 | 5.71 |
| 15/05/2023 | 6.24 | 5.71 |
| 16/05/2023 |  | 6.32 |
| 16/05/2023 |  | 6.32 |
| 16/05/2023 | 5.41 | 6.32 |
| 16/05/2023 | 6.16 | 6.32 |
| 16/05/2023 | 7.40 | 6.32 |

The moving Average works when its individual days but when I vary it to more than one it doesn't seem to be doing the right calculation (4 value set as day parameter):

[image: 4 Day Set]

My Measure calculation I have got the closest with is this, based on someone else's example:

```
Moving Avg Per Day = 
VAR _LastDate =
MAX (TBUData[Date])
VAR _Duration = [Parameter By Day]
VAR _CalculationPeriod =
FILTER (
ALL ( TBUData),
AND (
TBUData[Date] > _LastDate - _Duration, 
TBUData[Date] <= _LastDate 
)
)
VAR _MovingAverage =
IF (
COUNTROWS ( _CalculationPeriod ) >= _Duration, 
CALCULATE (
AVERAGEX(TBUData,[M2Average]), 
_CalculationPeriod
)
)
RETURN
_MovingAverage
```

For relationships I also have master date table although I am just trying to get it to work with the current table for now:

[image: Relationships]

I have tried quite a few different measures but have not managed to produce the right result

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your question to see i understood correctly (i have to do this via answer, because i cannot add comments yet):

It sounds to me like what you are trying to do is split your distinct dates for which you observations into bins by the size of n, starting with the smallest date and then calculate the average for all observations in those bins. Is that correct?

A way you could approach this is by really wrangling dax into submission:
You can calculate a table that ranks your destinct dates for which you have observations based on bin sizes of your input parameter. And then you leverage that calculated table to summarize your data based on the assigned bins.

Comment: That's what I am attempting to do yeah. Seems like a good idea, will give it a go